# Is it possible to have Nunit and SpecRun as UnitTestProviders at one time.?

Tags: nunit, specflow, specrun

For Parallel Test Execution I need "NUnit" but I also like reports from SpecRun.
Can anyone please help me to guide How to mention two UnitTestProviders in App.config.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have both unit test providers.
For running the Scenarios in parallel, you can also use SpecRun (SpecFlow+Runner). It has much more features than NUnit to execute in parallel.

Here are a sample for the different test thread isolation modes: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/TestThreadIsolation

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+.

Comment: Hi , In your solution TestThreadIsolation is for Parallel Test Execution?

Comment: Yes. The SpecFlow+Runner has different ways to execute scenarios in parallel. The setting for it is called TestThread Isolation.

Comment: I am very new coding , I was going through some Tutorials. I am not really clear how exactly to start with this parallel test execution with SpecFlow. I will check if I can get some tutorial on it. Than you so much for your support.

Comment: I would also like to know now my current Project I have UnitTestProvider as NUnit. Is it possible to change it to SpecRun? For this only App.Config file has to change along with Nuget Packages? or few more changes . Please guide me.

Comment: You need to set the unitTestProvider to SpecRun and add the plugins. See https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/blob/master/TestThreadIsolation/TestThreadIsolation/App.config#L38